# Java - overlay 2 images - above image get the form of below image

Tags: java

I want to done this, using java:

[image]

I can use javafx by applying blend mode on top image. In this case I use `linear burn`.

But this is not ok. If I use other colors, `linear burn` is no longer ok(top image color is changed to much), I need to use other blend mode.

So, my question is this: There is a library which can transform(`morph?`) top image by what is under it?(I don't know how exactly to explain, leave a comment if you don't understand)

**Edit 1:**

Here is an example where `linear burn` is not good:

[image]

In this case I should apply `exclusion` blend mode. Also `exclusion` is still not very good, but is the one which nearly keep the original color of top image(blue).

My intention is to create an app which does this blend mode automatically, but I can't find a rule or a blend mode which work in all cases. There could be any kind  color for both layers, top and bottom.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're actually trying to do and what you get instead.  Transforming an image (i.e. moving pixels around) wouldn't normally be something I'd expect from using a "blend mode" (which in my understanding just defines how two pixels are "blended" into one, e.g. by addition, multiplication etc.).

Comment: There are plenty of image processing/manipulation libraries/tools out there. I'm curious as to why you are using JavaFX for this, since that is more gui focused?

Comment: You are probably looking for something like this: http://im4java.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Thomas My target is to make visible the bevels from bottom image to top image. I tried with `blendmode` because I saw it can result what I want, but just in some cases.

Comment: @PiRocks I don't have gui. I apply blendmode(with javafx) and transform it into an `BufferedImage` and save it as file.

Comment: Well, that should be possible by blending the images. To better understand your problem could you post a few images on the input images, what you'd expect and what you get instead?

Comment: So you basically want to keep the luminosity of the bottom image, i.e. the "light and shade", while using the color of the top image? I'm not sure there is a built-in blend mode for that but you could try the following: 1) build a grayscale version of the original/bottom image which should represent the luminosity of that image 2) multiply the top image by the grayscale image built in step 1 - don't change the alpha channel though - and finally 3) blend the top image into the bottom image based on its alpha channel (afaik the blend mode for that should be SRC_OVER).

Comment: @Thomas `So you basically want to keep the luminosity of the bottom image, i.e. the "light and shade", while using the color of the top image?` Exactly. I don't really understand your suggestion. Can you explain better here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206591/room-for-kunlun-and-thomas ?

Comment: I don't have the time to explain that much, especially not in a back and forth conversation. Basically my suggestion is: 1) create an intermediate grayscale image (use the power of google on how to do that) , 2) blend your overlay with that image, 3) blend the original image and the result of step 2. - So you're working with 3 images: the original ("t-shirt"), an intermediate grayscale version of that and the overlay ("color").